# Kubernetes question during CKA exam, how would you build this?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I was doing the CKA and stumbled upon a question I couldn't figure out. I don't remember all the details, but it goes something like this:

Get the **top 1 node/pod by CPU** consumption and place it in a file at {path}.

```
kubectl top nodes/pod --sort-by cpu <-- this orders by ascending. So you have to hardcode the last node/pod.
```

Comment: is the requirement to come up with the code, generating that file? or manually copy/paste the name of the busiest pod into the file is acceptable? In either case - an answer from @Karan below would do it. I'll be surprised if the exam asks for the code... It might take considerable time and experience parsing the kubectl output that has very little to do with your knowledge of k8s.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to extract out the name of the top pod and save it in the file you can do this:

> Let us say you have 3 pods:

```sh
$ kubectl top pod --sort-by cpu
NAME                            CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
nats-depl-6c4b4dfb7c-tjpgv      2m           4Mi
project-depl-595bbd56db-lb6vb   8m           180Mi
auth-depl-64cccc484f-dn7w5      4m           203Mi
```

You can do this:

```sh
$ kubectl top pod --sort-by cpu | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'}
chat-depl-6dd798699b-l7wcl   #### < == returns name of the pod

## you can redirect it to any file 
$ kubectl top pod --sort-by cpu | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} > ./file_name
$ cat ./file_name 
chat-depl-6dd798699b-l7wcl   #### < == returns name of the pod
```